# How to pass props to React router

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm trying to pass props to a component using react router like so:

```
   <Login
            id={this.state.id}
            password={this.state.password}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
            error={this.state.error}
          />
```

How do I do exactly that but with a react router, and how do I use it in the component itself?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
  <Route
            path="/"
            component={Login}
            components={{
              id: this.state.id,
              password: this.state.password,
              onChange: this.onChange,
              onSubmit: this.onSubmit,
              error: this.state.error
            }}
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

Create `Login` component as child of route:

```
<Route path="/">
    <Login id={this.state.id} ... />
</Route>
```

UPD: As trixn noted, it is better to use render function to render component only when route matches

```
<Route path="/" render={ () => (
    <Login id={this.state.id} ... />
)}/>
```

Comment: Careful, the children of a `Route` are always rendered, not matter if the path matches or not. For rendering of a match use the `render` prop.

Comment: trixn can you write an aswer describing how to use render prop? I cant find a proper syntax anywhere.

Comment: @AlexK please check the duplicate post

Comment: @AlexK For reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func

Comment: trixn In that post hes not passing any props at all, so the syntax is not clear to me, i'm passing alot of props that contains callback functions, how do I write that? can you please write an example? I will delete this post after that.. I just want to know ><

Comment: @Shubham Khatri  That post is incredibly unclear, I have no idea after reading it how to refer that to my question, a function render(props), what enters the props? how do I send it there?, please help><

Comment: If only you tried to read the question and the answer properly, Anyways

`<Route
            path="/"
            render={(props) => <Login  {...props} 
              id= {this.state.id}
              password= {this.state.password}
              onChange={this.onChange}
              onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
              error={this.state.error}
            />}
          />`

Comment: @AlexK The props to the render function are the `Route` props and you can of course add your own props to the components that it renders. It's all clearly described in the documentation as well as in the duplicate questions answer. Please take your time to read that carefully and you can answer your question.